# How to Generate P2SH Address from XPUB Ledger

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, p2sh, ledger-hardware-wallet

I'm trying to Generate unused receiving Addresses for a Segwit P2SH wallet in my Ledger. I tried `https://pypi.org/project/bitcoinlib/` but without success, the addresses weren't right.

This is from my Ledger:

```
{
  "xpub": "xpub...",
  "index": 0,
  "freshAddressPath": "49'/0'/0'/0/6",
  "id": "js:2:bitcoin:xpub...:segwit",
  "blockHeight": 753361
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ledger is using [incorrect version prefix](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-live-desktop/issues/2527). Most libraries/wallets/online tools use [ypub format](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xpub_version_bytes.html) for P2SH address

To make this work you can use any of the following tools to convert you xpub to ypub:

- https://www.blockonomics.co/views/segwit_xpub_convert.html
- https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/